# Editing a latex class file

Tags: document-classes, editors

I am new to Latex so I would like to ask you for some help, I was provided with a predefined class file (.cls) to fulfill the format requirements for my undergraduate thesis book and now I am trying to adapt a similar structure for my master thesis book.

The cls file without any modification is properly working in the Lyx environment for Latex. But once I slightly modify the cls file using the Notepad text editor, then the document doesn´t compile in LyX.

My question is how should I edit the contents of the class file, so it allows the document to be compiled? Do I need to compile the class file in a Tex editor? is it texWorks a good option?

I would appreciate your comments! Thank you in advance

Comment: This has also been asked on the LyX mailing list.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What kind of modifications are done? What is the error message reported by TeX?

Comment: The reported error is \document{begin} is missing. In some parts of the code I just want to change part of the text to be shown
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{tesisusb}
              [2004/08/06 v1
clase para LaTeX consistente con el formato del Decanato de Postgrado USB]
....
  \begin{center}%
    \includegraphics[scale=.4]{cebolla}\\
    \large{UNIVERSIDAD SIM\'ON BOL\'IVAR}\\
   ....
In this example, I only changed the part    
\large{UNIVERSIDAD SIM\'ON BOL\'IVAR}\\  
replaced with
   \large{X UNIVERSITY}\\

Comment: Try this: Start from the fresh (working) original cls file. DO NOT EDIT IT IN NOTEPAD. Instead, get the free Notepad++ editor for Windows (it is also Portable). Edit it using that, being sure that you have it set to retain the original encoding and line endings. That might or might not help, but it is a good guess.

Comment: Editing a cls file is not for those new to LaTeX.  Are you really sure that's the best way to do it?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am not even changing the order of commands either the dimensions of the page, I just want to edit some text words that appear in the structure, but I want to keep the exact same structure previously defined

Comment: RobtA I will follow your advice and report the result of it, hope it works